# Is this the right way to test if a field has been left empty?

Tags: swift3

This is inside a function, so that any textField passed as argument can respond to the method `checkForEmptyFields`:

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkForEmptyFields(sender:)), 
for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
```

This is the method `checkForEmptyFields`:

```
 func checkForEmptyFields(sender:UITextField){

        self.loginButton.isEnabled = (sender.text?.trim().isEmpty)! == false

    }
```

This is a simple extension of String for manage the trimming:

```
extension String
{
    func trim() -> String
    {
        return self.trimmingCharacters(in: NSCharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    }
}
```

Anything seems to work just fine but I'd like to know if this is the right way to proceed and if I forgot something important (or I made any mistake). Thanks!

Comment: Force unwrapping is _never_ the right way!

Comment: Problem is... that value can in real life never be nil, neither if you assign nil directly (please, correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: I think that comes under the category of "famous last words". Eventually you'll figure out that it's simpler, and safer, just to never force unwrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would probably be safer to also ensure that the text is not nil.

```
func checkForEmptyFields(sender: UITextField) {
    let isTextEmpty = sender.text?.trim().isEmpty ?? true
    self.loginButton.isEnabled = !isTextEmpty
}
```

Your overall approach seems fine though.

---

As @matt has suggested in the comments, it's possible to encapsulate some of this behavior into an extension on `UITextField`.

```
extension UITextField {
    var isEmpty: Bool {
        return self.text?.trim().isEmpty ?? true
    }
}
```

Your function could be simplified to this:

```
func checkForEmptyFields(sender: UITextField) {
    self.loginButton.isEnabled = !sender.isEmpty
}
```

---

A side note: The "Swiftier" name for your extension is `trimmed()`, as it is returning a new `String` instance. This adheres to the [Swift API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/).

Comment: Why not advise that this be an extension on UITextField itself?

Comment: @matt That's a good idea! I'll update my answer with that option as well.

Comment: @nathan: problem is... as far as I know... that text can't be nil (I could not find a single case...). That is: theoretically speaking of course it is safer to implement it the way you do but if you directly assign nil from obj-c or swift nothing really happens (please, correct me if I'm wrong, I'm incredibly good at being wrong)   :-)   The editingChanged is in my first line of code (or are you suggesting a different thing?). Thanks both for your suggestions, they are really appreciated  :-)

Comment: @3000 While the `text` property of a `UITextField` is probably never going to be `nil`, it's a public API that's marked as optional, so it should be handled as if it could be `nil`. And yes, you're right about the `editingChanged` event. I mis-read it as something else.

Answer (score 1):

Per my comment above, don't force unwrap. Really!

I'd probably handle it like…

```
func checkForEmptyFields(sender: UITextField) {
    if let trimmedText = sender.text?.trim(), !trimmedText.isEmpty {
        loginButton.isEnabled = true
    } else {
        loginButton.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

It's more verbose, but I think this clearly states your intent - nil coalescing can sometimes be confusing to read and debug (should it be `?? true` or `?? false`?)